# Apache Camel aggregator with parallelProcessing completion callback

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel aggregator with **parallelProcessing** to process aggregated exchanges concurrently:

```
from("direct:test")               
            .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy())
            .completionSize(10)
            .completionTimeout(3000)
            .parallelProcessing()
            .to("direct:test2")
            .log("Completed!") //executed for each aggregated exchange  
            .end();
```

What I need is to get a callback when **all** aggregated exchanges are processed and log "Completed!" after that.

Currently, (see the log statement above) - it's getting executed for each aggregated exchange.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by all aggregated messages?

Comment: For example If I have 38 messages - 4 batches will be created (10, 10, 10, 8) and processed in parallel. I need to know when all batches are processed not when one of them (that's how it currently behaves),

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to log "Completed!" in different route. Someting like this:

```
from("direct:start")
        .split(body())
        .to("direct:test")
        .end()
        .log("Completed!");

from("direct:test")
        .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy())
        .completionSize(10)
        .completionTimeout(3000)
        .parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:test2");

from("direct:test2")
        .log("do something");
```

Comment: I've already tried that. This only works if parallel processing is disabled. With parallel processing enabled it logs "Completed" very early before any aggregated batch is processed.

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate splitted body? Have you tried SPLIT_COMPLETE constant? https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#SPLIT_COMPLETE